# Word Error "Word could not create the work file. Check the temp environment variable"

Tags: vbscript, ms-word, asp-classic, temp

My script in VBScript open a word document but when Word is called I have the error "Word could not create the work file. Check the temp environment variable".

```
Set WordDoc=WordApp.Documents.Add(*MyDoc*)
```

I know that my script works because it works on my local machine but i have the error message on my server.

I tried a lot of things (register key) but it doesn't works...

Someone have an idea ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Asp classic or vbscript?
This is not a good idea to open Word from asp classic server side.
See this posts : https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office

Comment: To answer your question. I will tell Word is not fully installed in the profile your script is running, or it doesn't have right permission.  First login on your server with the user your script is running and start Word.
You can give permission in dcomcnfg : https://forums.asp.net/t/1177636.aspx?Word+Automation+Multiple+DCOM+Errors+Behavior